# Visual studio code and vagrant integration

Tags: go, vagrant, visual-studio-code

I am using MacOS and vagrant for Go development. I don't want install any development packages like Go, npm etc. on my host machine (MacOS). All of dev softwares installed on vagrant.

But there is a problem with [vscode-go](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go) plugin, Because it requires few go packages like go vet, goimport etc. those packages installed on remote host (vagrat)

So how can I say to vscode that run these commands on remote host?

Comment: Couldn't you use `glide` to install the packages to a local vendor and export the local Go path in vscode so that vscode know's where to look and install stuff.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but my previous research indicates this isn't (easy) to do. Just install Go on your host machine (MacOS).

Comment: @therobinkim i think so :) i wasted about 48 hours about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make a nfs share on the GOPATH environment variable in vagrant. On your Mac define also a GOPATH env variable. That way vscode can install the tools on your vagrant.

Although not sure this covers Mac vs Linux binaries.

Another approach might be too create bash aliases/functions which invoke the command over ssh.

I wrote a blog post on how to set up vscode on windows. I would really recommend to install tools natively. Go tooling is small, super fast and doesn't add lot of bloat to your system. E.g. PHP ads lots of crap etc.

https://marcofranssen.nl/start-on-your-first-golang-project/

Might clarify some stuff for you.